# Guardar una base de datos en la tarjeta sd

Tags: java, android, sqlite

como puedo guardar mi base de datos en la sd de mi celular?
Aqui la tengo creada:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

String tabla ="CREATE TABLE Datos (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, N text, C text, R1 INTEGER, R2 INTEGER, R3 INTEGER, P4 text, P5 text)";

public DB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(tabla);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNva) {
    //Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Datos");

    //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
    db.execSQL(tabla);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Cuando crees la base de datos debes introducir el path donde quieres guardarla, el path se le pasa al super en tu constructor mediante el parámetro "name".

```
super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Comment: Gracias, pero donde pongo ese codigo, en DB.java?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez parece que sí, en el constructor de tu clase.